# elasticsearch で、英単語のトークンをカタカナに変換するフィルターはありますか?

Tags: elasticsearch, 日本語

Elasticsearch の analyzer は character filter, tokenizer, token filter から構成されますが、このうち英単語のトークンを受け取って、そのヨミをカタカナとして出力するような token filter の実現方法ないしライブラリなどはありますか?

以下のような token 変換を行ってほしいと考えています。

- `question` => `クエスチョン`
- `answer` => `アンサー`